# Change plotly express "color" variable with button

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly, plotly-express

I would like to create a plotly plot where I can change the value of the plotly express `color` argument via a [button](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/updatemenus/#layout-updatemenus-items-updatemenu-buttons). I am using [plotly.express.scatter](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.scatter) for this.

For example, the initial plot shown is `px.scatter(df, "sepal_length", "sepal_width", color="species")`. Changing from "species" to "petal length" in a dropdown menu would update the plot so that instead `color="petal_length"`. If it makes a difference, "species" uses the default discrete color sequence while "petal_length" uses the default continuous color scale.

The code I have so far makes the initial plot and dropdown buttons, but choosing the buttons has no effect. I don't understand how to get the plotly express `color` argument passed through this [`Plotly.update`](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyupdate) interface.

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv")
fig = px.scatter(df, "sepal_length", "sepal_width", color="species")

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(
                    args=["color", "species"],
                    label="species",
                    method="update"
                ),
                dict(
                    args=["color", "petal_length"],
                    label="petal length",
                    method="update"
                ),
            ]),
            showactive=True,
            x=0.05,
            xanchor="left",
            y=1.06,
            yanchor="top"
        ),
    ]
)

fig.update_layout(
    annotations=[
        dict(text="color", x=0.015, xref="paper", y=1.05, yref="paper",
             align="left", showarrow=False),
    ])

fig.show()
```

[image: Plotly scatterplot with dropdown menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For color='species', three graphs are internally created for each categorical variable. And color='petal_length' consists of a single graph data. So, it is possible to handle this by setting the drop-down to show/hide the graph. The actual code reuses the data created by express.scatter. The data for each graph will be configured in a graph object; three will be shown and one will be hidden. Set the button to restyle as a function of the button.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv")
fig1 = px.scatter(df, "sepal_length", "sepal_width", color="species")
fig2 = px.scatter(df, "sepal_length", "sepal_width", color="petal_length")

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(fig1.data[0], visible=True))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(fig1.data[1], visible=True))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(fig1.data[2], visible=True))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(fig2.data[0], visible=False))

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(
                    args=["visible", [True,True,True,False]],
                    label="species",
                    method="restyle"
                ),
                dict(
                    args=["visible", [False,False,False,True]],
                    label="petal length",
                    method="restyle"
                ),
            ]),
            showactive=True,
            x=0.05,
            xanchor="left",
            y=1.2,
            yanchor="top"
        ),
    ]
)

fig.update_layout(
    annotations=[
        dict(text="color", x=0.01, xref="paper", y=1.16, yref="paper",
             align="left", showarrow=False),
    ])
fig.update_layout(xaxis_title_text='sepal_length', yaxis_title_text='sepal_width', legend_title_text='species')
fig.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works great, thanks! I was easily able to add a `sepal_width` choice too. I created a `fig3` and added its trace like what you did with `fig2`. For the `visible` args in the button dicts I added new `False`s at the ends for the first two and the new one is `[False,False,False,False,True]`.